# Empty folders when using Copy-Item Network Drive to Local Drive

Tags: powershell

I'm currently using this Powershell script

```
Function Copy-ItemUNC { 
    New-PSDrive -Name "B" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\ServerName\serverupdates\deploy\Program Files\"  

    Copy-Item -Path "\\servername\serverupdates\deploy\Program Files\*" -Destination 'C:/Program Files'; 
}
```

When I run the script it creates the folders but there are no subfolders within them.

Second problem I have is that I have to manually open Windows Explorer and type in the path to connect to it first in order for this script to even run. Is there a way to fix that too?

Comment: Please update the code in your question - that code won't run as you have posted it.

Comment: That's all I have, it works if I open Windows Explorer first and go to \\ServerName\serverupdates\deploy\Program Files\ but it will only copy the folders without the subfolders. All I'm trying to do is copy the folders and subfolders from a network drive, do you have a better method to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: But the formatting is not correct. You have pasted a jumble of lines and they are run together. Fix that first as it's hard to tell what your script really looks like.

Comment: Ok I fixed it up, is it better?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just type `robocopy "\\ServerName\serverupdates\deploy\Program Files" "C:\Program Files" /E`? (Run `robocopy /?` for instructions.)

Comment: Tried it, I get an error stating 

Error:Invalid Parameter #3 : "C:\Program"

Comment: You are missing a `"` character. Look very carefully at the command I posted.

Comment: Got it working thank you, I used the IP address instead of the server name which fixed the problem. However, I had to go into Windows Explorer first and connect to that network drive using the IP address THEN run the powershell script. Is there anyway around that?

Comment: You are asking a security/authentication question. That depends. You can ask about that on superuser or serverfault.

Comment: Does it work if you do a `Test-Connection` first? Maybe `Test-Path` might help, run that first then if it fails to find the path, `Test-Connection` and re-test the path to see if it opened perhaps a socket or port.

Comment: @user2734259 Yeah I tried, it tells me The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are not asking for subdirs, as that requires you to do this.

```
Copy-Item -Recurse

-Recurse <SwitchParameter>
    Indicates that this cmdlet performs a recursive copy.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                False
    Accept pipeline input?       False
    Accept wildcard characters?  false

(Get-Command -Name Copy-Item).Parameters.Keys
Get-Help -Name Copy-Item -Full
Get-Help -Name Copy-Item -Examples


This command copies the mar1604.log.txt file to the C:\Presentation directory. The command does not delete the original file.
Example 2: Copy the contents of a directory to another directory
PS C:\>Copy-Item "C:\Logfiles" -Destination "C:\Drawings" -Recurse
```

So, this line should be like this..

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\servername\serverupdates\deploy\Program Files\*" -Destination 'C:/Program Files' -Recurse
```

You also do not really need this..

```
New-PSDrive -Name "B" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\ServerName\serverupdates\deploy\Program Files\"
```

... based on what you are after. Especially since you are not using it anywhere in your code. That semi-colon is also not needed.